# Hybris Delete Duplicate Product Data

Tags: duplicates, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

Anyone knows how to create a code to delete duplicate product data in Hybris? either using an impex script or modifying the code?

Comment: duplicate product(Article Number) in the same catalog(stage version)? or you mean to say duplicate product data having different article number

Comment: duplicate product with the same product name in the same catalog version, hope you can help, thanks

Comment: find my answer below

Answer (score 2):

> Question: **How to delete Hybris Products having a duplicate name?**

You can run **SQL / flexible query** to find duplicate products and then delete those list of pk using SQL query.

### List of pks to be removed

```
select MIN({p.pk}) as pks
 from {Product! as p

 JOIN CatalogVersion as CV on {p.catalogversion}={CV:PK} and {CV:version} = 'Online' 
 JOIN Catalog as C on {CV:catalog}={C:PK} and {C:id}='myProductCatalog'
 } 
 group by {p:name}
 having 
   count(*) > 1
```

---

### Run the remove query

Remove all pks get from above query. Repeat this for the `Online` version as well.

---

### You can find [detail steps here](https://hybrisdeveloper.blogspot.in/2018/03/delete-hybris-products-having-duplicate.html)

Comment: I believe that, after finding out the list of PKs to be removed, the removal should be performed with a groovy script which will do something like this:           **ProductModel product = modelService.get(PK.fromLong(pkLong));


modelService.remove(product);**  By deleting the items directly from the DB, the interceptors( e.g **ValidateInterceptor**) are being bypassed. Also, by using the ModelService the partOf is taken into consideration during removal, and those are the reasons I consider this to be a much cleaner solution of deletion

Comment: @dj_frunza yes, truly said!! One should delete Hybris item through `modelservice`, You can find `groovy` script to remove duplicate product in my post (detail steps)

Answer (score 0):

First of all, find the duplicated CMSItems using following flexiblesearch

```
SELECT {UID} as uid,{CatalogVersion} as CatalogVersion , count(1) as cnt from {CMSItem} GROUP BY {UID},{CatalogVersion} HAVING COUNT(1) > 1
```

then delete the duplicated ones.